# require_once(CRM/Core/Payment/SecurePay.php) failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Civi\Payment\System::getByProcessor()

Tags: payment-processor

I have been working on a site which was recently upgraded from 3.4.8 to 4.6.0
I am getting an error in error log which states that

> Warning: require_once(CRM/Core/Payment/SecurePay.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   Civi\Payment\System::getByProcessor() (line 52 of
>   /sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Payment/System.php)

I did not find any civicrm extension with respect to SecurePay.
I found securepay file here which i placed at CRM/Core/Payment/SecurePay.php :https://github.com/hash-bang/PHP-SecurePay

Only if go to database and disable securepay payment processor it fixes the error

```
UPDATE `pysecure_civi3`.`civicrm_payment_processor` SET `is_active` = '0' WHERE `civicrm_payment_processor`.`id` = 4;
```

where id= 4 is securepay payment processor.

Comment: Having same problem. I'm not using SecurePay. I am using PayPal. Just upgraded from 4.7.28 to 4.7.29 and now my client's contribution pages are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Using a library that is not customised for CiviCRM will not work. Maybe the pre-upgrade system (the 3.4.8 version) had a custom made payment processor for SecurePay. Look if you can find the file SecurePay.php in the backup of the old installation.